# Generating N recommendations per person in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher, collaborative-filtering

I follow [this tutorial](http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-build-a-recommendation-engine/) about collaborative filters in Neo4j.
In this tutorial, we first create a toy movie graph, as follows:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/developer-resources/cypher/movies_actors.csv" AS line
WITH line
WHERE line.job = "ACTED_IN"
MERGE (m:Movie {title:line.title}) ON CREATE SET m.released = toInt(line.released), m.tagline = line.tagline
MERGE (p:Person {name:line.name}) ON CREATE SET p.born = toInt(line.born)
MERGE (p)-[:ACTED_IN {roles:split(line.roles,";")}]->(m)
RETURN count(*);
```

Next, we propose five possible co-actors for Tom Hanks:

```
MATCH (tom:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie1)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coActor:Person),
       (coActor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie2)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coCoActor:Person)
WHERE tom.name = "Tom Hanks"
AND   NOT    (tom)-[:ACTED_IN]->()<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coCoActor)
RETURN coCoActor.name, count(distinct coCoActor) as frequency
ORDER BY frequency DESC
LIMIT 5
```

What if I want to perform such an operation on every person who acted in "Apollo 13"? In other words, my task is to propose 5 possible co-actors to every person who acted in "Apollo 13".
How do I do this in an effective way?

Comment: The "co-actors" query you've posted actually fetches co-co-actors who _have not_ worked with Tom Hanks. Can you clarify what you need?

Comment: I'm actually pasting an example from a web page. And you are right, the goal is to find co-co-actors who have the potential to become co-actors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things here. The query you pasted doesn't really make any sense:

```
RETURN coCoActor.name, COUNT(DISTINCT coCoActor) AS frequency
```

This will always return a frequency of 1, so your `ORDER BY` is meaningless.

I think you meant this:

```
RETURN coCoActor.name, COUNT(DISTINCT coActor) AS frequency
```

Second thing is that you don't need the variables `movie1` and `movie2`; they're not used again in your query.

Finally, you need to assert that you're not recommending the same actor to him or herself:

`WHERE actor <> coCoActor`

To actually answer your question:

```
// Find the Apollo 13 actors.
MATCH (actor:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie {title:"Apollo 13"})

// Continue with query.
MATCH (actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coActor:Person),
      (coActor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coCoActor:Person)
WHERE NOT (actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coCoActor) AND
      actor <> coCoActor

// Group by actor and coCoActor, counting how many coActors they share as freq.
WITH actor, coCoActor, COUNT(DISTINCT coActor) AS freq

// Order by freq descending so that COLLECT()[..5] grabs the top 5 per row.
ORDER BY freq DESC

// Get the recommendations.
WITH actor, COLLECT({name: coCoActor.name, freq: freq})[..5] AS recos
RETURN actor.name, recos;
```

Comment: The last `ORDER BY` orders by the frequency. Come come the results are grouped by `actor`? Does the last `WITH` statement ensure this?